# Issue with meteorJS object publishing

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-publications

I have issue with publishing data for my jQuery plug in. The plugin is autoform addition package which is defined like this:

```
Products.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({

  tooteNimetus:  {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      type: "selectize",
      options: function () {
        return productList
      }
    }
```

I need to define this productList.

When I define it as an object:

```
productList = [{label: "AXPK Plus 4G60", value: 2001244}]
```

, it works percectly

But I need to get the productList from collection, so I defined it like this:

```
ProductMap = new Mongo.Collection("productMap");

ProductMap.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    label: {
        type: String,
        label: "Toote nimetus"
    },
    value: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Toote kood"
    },
    miinimumTakistus: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Toote miinimum takistus",
        decimal: true
    }
}));

productList = ProductMap.find({}).fetch();
```

Also my subs and publish:
in my /server:

```
Meteor.publish("productMap", function () {
    return ProductMap.find({});
});
```

Subs in lib/router:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('insert', {
        path: '/insert',
        template: 'insertProduct',
        waitOn: function() {
            [
             Meteor.subscribe('productMap'),
             Meteor.subscribe('products')
             ];
        }
    });
});
```

So the problem is that currently it finds my productList only when I have autopublish turned on. How do I publish/subscribe correctly to my:

```
productList = ProductMap.find({}).fetch();
```

Also with autopublish turned on my plugin works when I open new inprivate session and until I make a refresh in my browser window. After the refresh it doesn't work and I need to open new inprivate window. With hard defined object/array the plugin works great in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that waitOn expects you to return the array (you forgot to return the array):

```
waitOn: function() {
        return [
             Meteor.subscribe('productMap'),
             Meteor.subscribe('products')
             ];
        }
```

Remove the autopublish pacakge from your projects almost immediately. Things work with the package added because it publishes everything.